# How to manage package dependencies with gatsby-dev-cli?

Tags: gatsby

I have an intention to extend `gatsby-transformer-remark` with adding possibility of using `id` attribute inside a markdown.

When I'm trying to launch `yarn watch --scope=gatsby-transformer-remark` in local gatsby repo and `gatsby-dev` and `gatsby develop` in parallel inside my  test site directory I have build fails caused by the lack of installed dependencies of `gatsby-transformer-remark`.

Previously I'd followed this guide to prepare environment - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/how-to-contribute/#contributing-to-the-repo.

How do you handle package dependencies  with `gatsby-dev-cli`?

Comment: `yarn run bootstrap` should take care of that. Otherwise `cd` into the `gatsby-transformer-remark` directory and manually install via `npm install` or `yarn`.

Comment: I've runing it of course and it's not solving the problem. I have all `node_modules` in gatsby local repo, but they have not copied to the test site `node_modules` with `gatsby-dev` launching

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem occured with `remark-bracketed-spans` which I had added to `gatsby-transformer-remark` dependencies and if I want to use it with test site I need to install `remark-bracketed-spans` inside test site directory also